# Composition of a measurable function and a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$(X,\Phi_X)$ is a measurable space, $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. I have to prove or disprove $$\phi\circ f\text{ is measurable.}$$

Since $\phi$ is continuous, it is measurable, and the composition of measurable functions is measurable, then the proposition is true.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: I'd be careful with what you mean by "measurable".  In the Lebesgue sense, the composition of measurable functions in not necessarily measurable.

Comment: I'm not talking in the Lebesgue sense.

Comment: That is usually what someone means when they don't specify a modifier on measurable $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions.  My point is that it's the Borel-measurability of $\phi$ you need, so you should actually specify that (or specify precisely the measure spaces)

Comment: Right, thank you for the clarification!